# how to post a Tweet and @ some people

Tags: android, twitter, twitter4j

I want to post a tweet with image and text in my android app,but i want to @ some other people at the same time,how should I do?
the twett result that I get just like ,that is from my publish @ my friend.
my code:

```
            StatusUpdate statu = new StatusUpdate("tweet text");

            File tweetImg = getTwitterImagFile();

            statu.setMedia(tweetImg);

            mTwitter.updateStatus(statu);
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to add @[user_handle] to tweet text. If you are replying a tweet, you can set the parameter `in_reply_to_status_id` in the POST request.

See: https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/post/statuses/update

Comment: sorry,sir.I try to @[user] as a string to append the tweet text,but it can not show correctly.how should I add @[user_handle] to the text and what the format of @[user_handle].can you show some code.thank you very much!